# Assign Lambda Function To Specific VPC ID in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless framework to deploy a Python lambda function to AWS. In my `serverless.yml` file I have defined a function which I need to deploy to a VPC with specific ID as only that VPC has network connectivity needed to make some business related requests from the lambda function.

```
  customer_callback:
    vpc:
      subnetIds:
        - subnet-something
    handler: myservice/event_stream.customer_callback
```

In the documentation, the above example is what they mention as a way to attach the function to a VPC:

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/

However, the function is not deployed to a VPC at all, e.g. I end up with:

[image]

I have tried specifying VPC ID directly like this:

```
  customer_callback:
    vpc:
      id: vpc-something
    handler: myservice/event_stream.customer_callback
```

But that does nothing as well. The documentation for this issue is basically non-existent and I tried searching a lot so I finally have to post here to ask for help.

Comment: Hello Richard, did you find any solution on this? I'm trying to attach my lambda function to the default vpc without success :(

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Doesn't the answer below work for you?

Comment: @dashmug Thanks, indeed it worked. I had some other errors, that's why I thought that it didn't work at first.

Comment: Hello Richard! Did you find a solution to deploy your function using a specific VPC id? I'm having the exact same problem, with the following error: "EC2 Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound. EC2 Error Message: The security group 'sg-cfd1ccbd' does not exist"

Answer (score 11):

From https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#vpc-configuration:

> This object should contain the securityGroupIds and subnetIds array properties needed to construct VPC for this function.

```
functions:
  customer_callback:
    handler: myservice/event_stream.customer_callback
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - sg-deadbeef
      subnetIds:
        - subnet-fadecafe
```

You would also need to add VPC IAM Permissions.

> The Lambda function execution role must have permissions to create, describe and delete Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI). When VPC configuration is provided the default AWS AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole will be associated with your Lambda execution role.

To do this, add the following in your `serverless.yml`:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        Description: Creating policy for vpc connetion.
        Roles:
          - {"Ref" : "IamRoleLambdaExecution"}
        PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
              Resource: "*"
```

Comment: I believe the OP was asking about deploying to a specific VPC ID. I have the same scenario where I can deploy to the default VPC just fine, but when I specify a security group/subnet combination that exists in a different VPC, it throws an error that "the security group 'xxx' doesn't exist"

Comment: @lukiffer Are you referring to dedicated tenancy VPCs?

Comment: @lukiffer You're right. My answer only applies to default VPCs. I haven't seen anything about non-default VPCs yet.